# How can I remove in Python "-" from spaces and keep them between words?

Tags: python, string, whitespace

I have a string with different words in Python. The string is connected with a "-" between the words and the spaces, as shown in the example below.

```
asiatische-Gerichte----wuerzige-Gerichte----vegetarische-Sommerrolle--------Smokey-Pulled-Pork-Burger----
```

I tried using the replace and split method to remove the "-" in the spaces. However, I can only get it to remove them all, but I need the hyphens between the words.

My expected result is shown below:

```
asiatische-Gerichte wuerzige-Gerichte vegetarische-Sommerrolle Smokey-Pulled-Pork-Burger
```

Comment: You could use a [**`regex`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) or [**`groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Comment: Is there always more than one `-` in the spaces? Then use a regular expression that matches 2 or more `-`: `-{2,}`

Comment: It sure would help if you provided your expected result.

Comment: @PeterWood Im a totally newbie in regex. I will try it with groupby.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, there is pretty much always more than one space between words. But it can also happen that there is only one space between the words.

Comment: Then how do you expect to tell whether that one hyphen is a space that should be removed or a hyphen that should be kept?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve] and edit the question.

Comment: @Anon_test regex is probably easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace all occurrences of 2 or more dashes in a row with a space:

```
s = re.sub(r'-{2,}', ' ', s)
```

Comment: @Mark The answer is no.

Comment: Based on the expected result, you should be replacing with a space, not an empty string.

Comment: @TimurShtatland Thank you, it worked with the help of Barmar! I feel so stupid. Thank you to all of you guys for the time!

Comment: @Mark: Not really. Updated, thx.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression.

```
old_string = "asiatische-Gerichte----wuerzige-Gerichte----vegetarische-Sommerrolle--------Smokey-Pulled-Pork-Burger----"
new_string = re.sub('-{2,}', '-', old_string).strip('-')
print(new_string)
```